# NullPointerException when use findViewById() in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

This is my code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
adb.setView(LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom, null));

adb.setPositiveButton("Add",new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

                java.util.Date date = null;
                Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                date = cal.getTime();
            }                  
        });             
adb.show();
}
```

I have the NullPointerException in this line, and I think datePicker wasn't findById, because I use AlertDialog.Builder.

> cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());

I tried use `adb.findViewById();` but it'is a mistake (The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder).
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
```

this line to

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)adb.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
```

...............

try this one:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.main1, null);
adb.setView(view);
final Dialog dialog;
adb.setPositiveButton("Add",new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

        java.util.Date date = null;
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
        date = cal.getTime();
    }                  
});   
dialog = adb.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: `The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder` if I add to cast ((Dialog)adb).findViewById I have `Cannot cast from AlertDialog.Builder to Dialog`

Comment: If don't works, why you accepted it? EDIT: Yeah, the second part is the one that works. Use the inflated layout instead of the dialog.

Comment: The key for me was `view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);`, specifically that you used `view` rather than your `Activity` to call `findViewById()`

Comment: please, delete first example :)

Answer (score 2):

Search for the `DatePicker` using the `dialog` parameter:

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) ((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
```

Comment: Eclipse said `Cannot cast from AlertDialog.Builder to Dialog`

Comment: @pavelartlover Did you use my **exact** code, with the `dialog` parameter from the `onClick` method and you get that `Cannot cast...`?

Comment: I replace your `dialog` by my `adb`. Maybe I use wrong type of dialog in this case. I want to show custom dialog with datepicker and other stuff from my xml file, and two button like in alert dialog - Save and Cancel.

Comment: @pavelartlover Once again, use **exactly** what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be  the problem,

```
final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
adb.setView(LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom,null));
```

Use the below way to inflate the view and use the view object for getting the id.

```
 LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);

DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
```

Example:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog() {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(TicTacToe.this)
        //.setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
        .setTitle(getTitleText())
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .setPositiveButton("JOIN GAME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                try
                {
                    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
                        playerName = et.getText().toString();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        })
        .create();
return null;
```

}

Comment: yeah i forgot to inflate R.layout.xxx

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
First I must call the

> dialog.show(),

and only after it I was able to use

> dialog.findviewById(R.id.myID).

If I missed to call the show(), than I got a null back with findViewByID.

Answer (score 0):

A project clean and rebuild fixed this error for me (on Xamarin).